# Run java script command right after the page is loads

Tags: java

i open a web page through IE from java code as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(url).
```

My web page displays authentication screen with user name and password (pretty much the same user and password for all the users).

in addition, i have created java script that populates the user name and password automatically as hard coded. and it works fine if i run it manually while the focus is on my web page.

Is there any possibility to run the script through the above command?
i just want to open the page and that the user & password will be populated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your method of launching the browser is rather flaky.  What you're currently doing is running the URL as if it were a command, i.e. the name of a process to run.  This is similar to typing it at a command prompt or the Windows Run... dialog.  Fortunately in this case, Windows interprets an attempt to execute an HTTP URL by launching IE with that URL, but that's not likely to be consistent in other environments.  A better approach would be to use [Desktop.browse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29), which specifically launches the URL in the default browser.

As to your question itself, it's very unlikely this is possible.  You're spawning a new (IE) process, which is completely separate from your Java process.  Without some form of inter-process communication, Java won't be able to send commands to IE on the fly.  The only possible way this might work is by passing arguments to the command that are interpreted by the new process.  To my knowledge however there are no command-line arguments that will cause IE to run an arbitrary piece of JS once a page is loaded.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx eval looks like it may be of interest for IE 7 and under. (so long as OP is using hacked solutions anyway. I have a feeling this is for himself, and not going to have end-users)

Comment: @Cruncher Good spot!  I can't find any documentation about what it (used to) do, but it might well be hackable into a solution.

Comment: I looked for some documentation too, it looks like Microsoft doesn't want anybody to know much about it. I tested some things on my IE 8, and couldn't get any javascript to run though.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tonyschr/archive/2007/01/19/ie-automation-amp-tabs.aspx

This may be another possible solution. Probably better than the `eval` switch. Again, windows only of course

Answer (score -1):

To run code when the page loads. Put it in an onload function.

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your javascript code here
}
```

Comment: The OP is opening a webpage from Java, then needs to get his own javascript to run. He is not editing the javascript of the page